# Why do I get tkinter.TclError: bitmap not defined error?

Tags: python, tkinter, bitmap, tcl, png

```
from tkinter import *
from configparser import ConfigParser
from tkinter import messagebox
import requests

if weather:
    location_lbl['text'] = '{}, {}'.format(weather[0], weather[1])
    image_lbl['bitmap'] = 'icons/{}.png'.format(weather[4])
    temp_lbl['text'] = '{:.2f}°C, {:.2f}°F'.format(weather[2], weather[3])
    weather_lbl['text'] = weather[5]
```

I got this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "icons/50d.png" not defined
```

Please help me.

Comment: Would appreciate marking the below as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding, `image_lbl['bitmap']` is NOT used for showing png files or your loaded image files, its more like for showing the bitmaps loaded into tkinter:

```
image_lbl['bitmap'] = 'error' #or questionhead, warning, gray50, etc.
```

If you want to load a png image then use `tk.PhotoImage`, like:

```
img = tk.PhotoImage(file='icons/{}.png'.format(weather[4]))
image_lbl['image'] = img
```

Though its worth noting that for using `jpeg`, an additional module named `PIL` has to be used.

**Take a look at these, helpful links:**

[Bitmaps on tkinter](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_bitmaps.htm)

[PhotoImage on tkinter](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: I'd strongly suggest avoiding using the `bitmap` property on all modern interfaces. It's a relic of how things were done 30 years ago, and has been functionally irrelevant for at least 25 years.

Comment: @DonalFellows I agree, its quite archaic.

Comment: this will remove the errors but didn't show the image when runs

Comment: @SuprabhatKhot You have to keep reference to the image, read the link that i linked with the image. This Q is for the Q you had not for showing any other image.

Comment: @CoolCloud Ok I'll check, Thanks btw